# Lorentz invariant tensors of odd rank

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory

How to prove that Lorentz invariant tensors of odd rank are all zero? I somehow think that determinant or generator of the Lorentz group should be used.

Comment: In my view this issue concerns mathematical physics and, for that reason, should not be closed. The issue, in spite of being trivial to state, is quite difficult to fix.

Answer (score 3):

The non trivial Lorentz invariant tensors are constructed as tensor products and contractions of many copies of the metric and its inverse. Hence,  there are no odd rank invariant tensors, but the zero one. If you only consider the *proper* Lorentz group, you can also use the Ricci tensor which is however of even rank, so that the final result does not change.

This result is difficult to find in the literature and it is not so easy to rigorously prove.  Together I.Khavkine, I exploited that result in a joint work Commun. Math. Phys. 344  (2016), 581-620  DOI:10.1007/s00220-016-2618-7  https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1302

See Section 2.6 and References [3],[27] and [12] therein.